Sportypy can't see field
I am running code for the sportypy library to create an NHL Rink and I cannot see the displayed rink. The program runs without any errors, but I cannot see the rink that it creates.
I tried copying the code from the sportypy documentation and I was expecting for a picture of an NHL Rink to appear as a new tab in my browser.
Here is my code:
from sportypy.surfaces.hockey import NHLRink

nhl = NHLRink()
nhl.draw()


What environment are you running the code inside? If e.g. you're running inside a vm or a container, it would probably not show the graphics at all.

I am using PyCharm to run the code

Ok, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't show, then. I'd try William's proposition!

One option is to wrap it with a matplotlib plt.show() (Note: it does take a few minutes to render).
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from sportypy.surfaces.hockey import NHLRink

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nhl = NHLRink()
nhl.draw(ax=ax,display_range='full')
plt.show()

